# ImageView в ScrollView

Tags: android

Возможно ли в `ScrollView` разместить не только `TextView`, но и `ImageView` и если да, то какой java-код необходим? Вот xml код для самой картинки:

```
android:src="@mipmap/foto"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="center"
```

Возможно нужен какой-то метод для реализации задуманного.

Answer (score 2):

Вот краткий пример, в `ScrollView` поместили контейнер `LinearLayout`, а дальше, как обычно

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Используйте `setImageDrawable` или `setImageBitmap` или `setImageResource` для `ImageView`, что бы программно установить ваши входные данные.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, возьмите произвольный контейнер, например LinearLayout vertical и поместите в него ScrollView, а внутри него разместите TextView и ImageView

Comment: ок, но я имею в виду чтобы отображать textView в ScrollView необходим метод setText(), а какой метод нужен для отображения imageview?

Comment: setImageDrawable или setImageBitmap или setImageResource, все зависит от того, что у вас на входе

Comment: Вообще можешь юзать либу Picasso, мощный инструмент

Comment: А можно в самом Scrollview размещать imageview, не создавая дополнительных layout файлов?

Comment: В смысле доп. файлов, у тебя в любом случае будет 1 разметка

Comment: Хотя можно и без леймаутов только нужно будет все писать программно

Comment: в Scrollview рекомендуется использовать только 1 контейнер

Comment: Т,е возможен и такой вариант:                                                      <ScrollView>
              <TextView>
                    ...
            <TextView/>
                    <imageView>
                    ...
            <imageView/>
<ScrollView/>   ?